# Forwarding traffic to another pc on the same network to access another network

Tags: networking, windows-10

Is it possible to somehow "forward" all traffic from one computer destined for another network to another computer on the same network?

Here's an example to clarify.

Say we have Computer A and Computer B both on Network 1. Computer A is also connected to Network 2 via VPN. Computer B is not connected to Network 2 at all. Is it possible for Computer B to somehow access Network 2 through Computer A, by having Computer A simply "forwarding" all Computer B's outgoing traffic to Network 2?

Both Computer A and B are on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to [install the OpenSSH server on Computer A and OpenSSH client on Computer B](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), then you can make use of an OpenSSH feature called [dynamic port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Dynamic_Port_Forwarding) in simple cases. By connecting to Computer A via SSH on Computer B with dynamic port forwarding, a SOCKS proxy will be created on e.g. port 1080 in any proxy-aware program by running:

```
ssh -D 1080 name-or-ip-of-computer-a
```

This can then be used by setting localhost:1080 as a SOCKS proxy in any proxy aware programs.

For something more permanent, or if setting a proxy server is not a workable solution for the applications you want to use, you will probably want to set up a separate VPN. An easily installable option is [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com), which allows private users to set up their own VPNs for free, with the ability to fairly easily [route traffic for specific subnets via specific machines](https://tailscale.com/kb/1019/subnets/) or [route all of your computer's internet traffic via another machine](https://tailscale.com/kb/1103/exit-nodes/). These VPN connections are direct where possible, and relayed end-to-end encrypted when not, so Tailscale itself does not see any of the traffic between Computer A and Computer B.

Above all, make sure you're complying with the network security requirements of whatever VPN it is you're connecting to on Computer A!

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a few things to try out. Much appreciated. Wish me luck.